# Getting error "this domain is not registered with tiny cloud" even after checking API key and registered domains

Tags: php, tinymce

I'm trying to use tinymce and keep getting the error

"This domain is not registered with tiny cloud. Please review your Approved Domains"

I've triple checked the API key in my script tag:

```
<script src="https://cdn.tiny.cloud/1/5fl4k617wn4mn5373lymjfi4wxzk3uwku8uyw9pzpqhtzyrf/tinymce/5/tinymce.min.js" referrerpolicy="origin"></script>
```

And also verified that my domain is listed under my "approved domains" (dev.vmc.w3.uvm.edu)

I'm not sure what else could be wrong?

Comment: Same problem here, it shows even on localhost, which is a default for every plan.

Happened today, until today everything was right. The 30 days trial period ended a couple of weeks, but I'm under the community license and it was working alright until today.

Comment: I found yesterday that my colleague doesn't get the message on his machine, and if I use an Incognito window the message doesn't show up.  I cleared my cookies / cache thinking maybe it was something like that but that didn't help either.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you've already created an account, and verify if the API key is correct. After both are set, you want to set up the "Approved Domains" section in your Tiny account, then everything will probably work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this helps - but it looks like unless you added this domain the first time that you set up your account, it might take a little time for things to [update on their end](https://www.tiny.cloud/blog/how-to-get-tinymce-cloud-up-in-less-than-5-minutes/).

**It’s not a big deal if you do it later, just expect a short delay to domain updates as your changes propagate across our global CDN.**

Also, if that is a real API key in the tag you provided, it might be good to rotate that key so that this publicly viewed key is no longer usable, or accessible by others.